# Can not play video, can not figure out why

Tags: video, video-conversion

I have this video film that I can not play, and I try to figure out why, on ouput of mediainfo -l I get this:

```
Complete name                            : 101064-HD-FR.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 1.54 GiB
Duration                                 : 1h 26mn
Overall bit rate                         : 2 550 Kbps
Tagged date                              : UTC 2014-10-24 09:15:53
Writing application                      : Lavf56.1.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : encv / avc1 / mp4a
Duration                                 : 1h 26mn
Bit rate                                 : 2 404 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.104
Stream size                              : 1.45 GiB (94%)
Tagged date                              : UTC 2014-10-24 09:15:53
Encryption                               : Encrypted

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 1h 26mn
Duration_LastFrame                       : -5ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 138 Kbps
Nominal bit rate                         : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 84.9 MiB (5%)
Tagged date                              : UTC 2014-10-24 09:15:53
Encryption                               : Encrypted
```

When trying to play with mpv (tried other players also), I get this:

```
[libav/audio] aac: Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[libav/audio] aac: Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[libav/audio] aac: Input buffer exhausted before END element found
[libav/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (<unknown>)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 --alang=und (*) (aac)
Failed to initialize a video decoder for codec '<unknown>'.
Video: no video
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Encrypted. You'll need something which can play DRM video content, and the associated key, in order to decrypt and play the video.